# Validation in MVVM model

Tags: c#-4.0

Hai all,
         I am doing a project using MVVM model,can anyone help me by saying how can i validate my fields in this model.Validation means,if a text field where a name(example) is not added by the user,then a message want to be shown,using a pop up or anything.Nolramlly we were doing this by writing a function and this function will be called before saving or something,at that time if any of the Mandetory field is free then an error will be shown,only after filling that field only we can continue.How can i do this in MVVM model?

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm not 100% sure where you are going with this but I'm gonna give a example. Not sure how this would work with MVVM but I guess it should.

In your Model add this:

```
 public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return (GetRuleViolations().Count() == 0);
        }
    }

  public override IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            yield return new RuleViolation("Name can't be empty", "Name");

        else if (Name.Length >= 30)
            yield return new RuleViolation("Name can't be more then 30 letters", "Name");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address))
        {
            if (!Web.Contains("http"))
                yield return new RuleViolation("Address must be bla bal", "Address");
        }

        // and so on

        yield break;
    }
```

And create the RuleViolation class:

```
 public class RuleViolation
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; private set; }

    public RuleViolation(string errorMessage, string propertyName)
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }
}
```

Now when you call your IsValid method it will check every property. If you are using INotifyPropertyChanged I would add IsValid as a property to update each time you update any property that is validated. If you have a base model class you could add it there and define the rules in each derived class:

```
 public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return (GetRuleViolations().Count() == 0);
        }
    }

    public abstract IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations();
```

Now the question is how do you show this error in your UI. Well that depends on what the UI is. Let's assume WPF application. Then you need your Model to inherit IDataErrorInfo and you could use it like this:

```
#region IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;

            if (this.GetRuleViolations().Where(v => v.PropertyName == name).Count() > 0)
            {
                result = this.GetRuleViolations().Where(v => v.PropertyName == name).First().ErrorMessage;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Then in the XAML code:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource ValidationTextBox}" >
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <DataErrorValidationRule />
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>

<Style x:Key="ValidationTextBox" TargetType="TextBox" >
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                   Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you are using Asp.net as UI there are some built in methods for showing errors in forms there as well.

I could be way of and there might be better ways but I hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thank you Very much for your response,anyway i will try to implement this.

Comment: So what UI implementation are you using?